# objects in array are sort incorrectly

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, object

How can i sort this array by newUan price and price? if there are more code, then the function will be sorted incorrectly
i wrote code, but it works incorrectly

```
const sortedByPrice = () => {
 const sortPrice = products.slice()
  sortPrice.sort((a, b) => parseInt(b.price.newUan) - parseInt(a.price.newUan))
  return sortPrice;
  };

const products = [
{
    ratingReviews: '264 отзыва',
    price: {
        oldUan: '4 333 грн',
        newUan: '3 799 грн',
    },
    name: 'Motorola MOTO G4 (XT1622) Black',
}, {
    ratingReviews: '1355 отзывов',
    price: '4 999 грн',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy J7 J700H/DS Black + карта памяти 16гб + чехол + защитное стекло!',
}, {
    ratingReviews: '426 отзывов',
    price: '5 199 грн',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy J5 (2016) J510H/DS Black + защитное стекло + чехол!',
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because price does not always have `newUan` property. You can do something like this inside the `sort` callback, `parseInt(b.price.newUan || b.price)`. This says if `newUan` exists parse it into integer but if it doesn't then parse `price` into integer.

I've removed the whitespaces from the prices as well, so that it can be converted to integers properly.

See the snippet below:

```js
const products = [
  {
    ratingReviews: '264 отзыва',
    price: {
      oldUan: '4 333 грн',
      newUan: '3 799 грн',
    },
    name: 'Motorola MOTO G4 (XT1622) Black',
  },
  {
    ratingReviews: '1355 отзывов',
    price: '4 999 грн',
    name:
      'Samsung Galaxy J7 J700H/DS Black + карта памяти 16гб + чехол + защитное стекло!',
  },
  {
    ratingReviews: '426 отзывов',
    price: '5 199 грн',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy J5 (2016) J510H/DS Black + защитное стекло + чехол!',
  },
];

const sortedByPrice = () => {
  const sortPrice = products.slice();
  sortPrice.sort(
    (a, b) =>
      parseInt((b.price.newUan || b.price).replace(" ", "")) -
      parseInt((a.price.newUan || a.price).replace(" ", ""))
  );
  return sortPrice;
};

console.log(sortedByPrice());
```

Comment: So, if i don`t need to remove space between number
How can i solve this problem now?

Comment: @user402114 I've updated my answer, please check. You can remove the spaces inside the sort callback using `replace(" ","")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the existence of `newUan` using `||` operator and then have a fallback of `price` and accordingly proceed.
Also there shouldn't be space between `price` like `4 333`. This will cause `parseInt` to return `4`.

```js
const sortedByPrice = () => {
  const sortPrice = products.slice()
  sortPrice.sort((a, b) => {
    let first = a.price.newUan || a.price;
    let second = b.price.newUan || b.price;
    return parseInt(second) - parseInt(first);
  })
  return sortPrice;
};

const products = [{
    ratingReviews: '264 отзыва',
    price: {
      oldUan: '4333 грн',
      newUan: '3799 грн',
    },
    name: 'Motorola MOTO G4 (XT1622) Black',
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '1355 отзывов',
    price: '4999 грн',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy J7 J700H/DS Black + карта памяти 16гб + чехол + защитное стекло!',
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '426 отзывов',
    price: '5199 грн',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy J5 (2016) J510H/DS Black + защитное стекло + чехол!',
  },
  {
    ratingReviews: '426 отзывов',
    price: '2000 грн',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy J5 (2016) J510H/DS Black + защитное стекло + чехол!',
  }
];


console.log(sortedByPrice())
```